# Gnuplot: Use of "graph 0" and "graph 1" when drawing rectangles

Tags: gnuplot

I'd be happy about some enlightenment on the use of "graph 0" and "graph 1":

Goal is to draw rectangles into a graph, but while painting the whole background works, horizontal stripes don't, when I try to use graph 0 and graph 1 to indicate the left and right boundaries.

I'm following the second example at http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/rectangle.html

```
reset session
set xrange [0:6]
set yrange [0:25]

set obj 1 rect from graph 0,graph 0 to graph 1,graph 1 fc "red"   # paint the background

set obj 2 rect from graph 0,5 to graph 1,12 fc "green"            # produces nothing

set obj 3 rect from 'graph 0', 3 to 'graph 1',10 fc "blue"        # produces nothing 

set obj 4 rect from 'graph 0', 4 to 6,8 fc "yellow"               # this works. '...' and 6 required 

plot 'data02.txt'
```

What am I missing?

My gnuplot is 5.2.8 on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you write e.g. `'graph 0'` instead of `graph 0`?
And check `help coordinates`:

> If the coordinate system for x is not specified, first is used. If the
> system for y is not specified, the one used for x is adopted.

Hence, e.g. `graph 0, 5` and `graph 0, 12` will be outside of the graph. You should write `graph 0, first 5` and `graph 0, first 12` or `0,5` and `0,12` if you mean the x- and y-coordinates. Actually, in your case `graph 0` is identical with `first 0`. So, it depends what you want.

Check the following script.

**Script:**

```
### coordinate sytems graph and first
reset session

set xrange [0:6]
set yrange [0:25]

set obj 1 rect from graph 0,       0 to graph 1,        1 fc "red"
set obj 2 rect from graph 0, first 5 to graph 1, first 12 fc "green"
set obj 3 rect from graph 0, first 3 to graph 1, first 10 fc "blue"
set obj 4 rect from graph 0, first 4 to       6,        8 fc "yellow"

plot NaN notitle   # or plot some data
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, using "first" has solved my problem!

Trying 'graph 0' (the quotes) was just guesswork.